# What is wrong with my Trigger? Oracle SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sqlplus

### SQLPLUS TRIGGER COMPILATION ERRORS

I am new to oracle sqlplus, and I am trying to create a trigger that fires when a customer deposits or withdraws money from their account, showing the account_no, type of transaction (deposit/withdraw), transaction amount, old balance and new balance:

here is the code for table (which i have already created):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS,
(
  custname VARCHAR2(20)NOT NULL,
  account_no NUMBER(20)NOT NULL,
  cur_balance NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (account_no)
 );
```

This is the trigger code which i have compiled but it keeps on giving errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER account_tx   
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF cur_balance ON customers  
FOR EACH ROW  
DECLARE   
   new_balance number;   
BEGIN CASE WHEN :NEW.cur_balance <:OLD.cur_balance THEN 'WITHDRAWAL';  
ELSE 'DEPOSIT';   
   new_balance := :NEW.cur_balance  - :OLD.cur_balance;   
   dbms_output.put_line('Old balance: ' || :OLD.cur_balance);   
   dbms_output.put_line('New balance: ' || :NEW.cur_balance);   
   dbms_output.put_line('Transaction Amount: ' || new_balance);  
END CASE;  
END;  
/
```

Comment: with this trigger i get this error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITHDRAWAL" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
         raise return select update while with <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
         continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
         savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
         json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array

Comment: You need an assignment such as `:NEW.cur_balance := 'WITHDRAWAL';` there, rather than a logic alike a boolean expression... Btw, there's a typo (comma) after table's name within the create statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE statement is messed-up You need to assign the result of the CASE statement to a variable, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER account_tx
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF cur_balance ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
new_balance number;
trans_type varchar2(30);
BEGIN 
trans_type := CASE WHEN :NEW.cur_balance <:OLD.cur_balance THEN 'WITHDRAWAL'ELSE 'DEPOSIT' END;
new_balance := :NEW.cur_balance  - :OLD.cur_balance;
dbms_output.put_line('Old balance: ' || :OLD.cur_balance);
dbms_output.put_line('New balance: ' || :NEW.cur_balance);
dbms_output.put_line('Transaction Amount: ' || new_balance);
dbms_output.put_line('trans type: ' || trans_type);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your create table isn't valid, extra comma first line

When you get errors, you can see them with the 'show errors' command.

Running your code, I see this:

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for TRIGGER ACCOUNT_TX:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/57     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITHDRAWAL" when expecting one
     of the following:
     ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
     raise return select update while with <an identifier>
     <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
     continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
     savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
     json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array

SQL>
```